# ACL helper library for Python 3.x

Tags: library, python, user-management

I am in the course of developing a tool which provides different features to different users depending on which permissions were granted.

Note that I am *not* looking for [pylibacl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylibacl) or similar tools which provide access to a file system's ACL.

**Requirements**

- Flexible support for many roles in different scenarios.
  For example, John Doe could be an administrator in "Project A" whereas he is only a guest in "Project B".
- Inheritance of roles, e.g. an administrator of a project has got guest privileges as well.
- Ability to export permissions and user roles to a data format which can be saved on disk and later retrieved again.
- Compatible with Python 3.x

I found [kyleterry/simpleacl-piy](https://github.com/kyleterry/simpleacl-py), however, it does not seem to meet my last two criterias.